# No ItemTemplate property for Picker in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, picker

I want to create picker for items but display not only text but icon as well. I tried using ItemTemplate property but it is not working. How can I replace it and create picker with text and icon in Xamarin Forms app?

Code I tried:

```
<Picker ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IconLabelTemplate}">
    <Picker.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:IconLabelView}">
            <local:IconLabelView IconSource="tablet_icon.png" Text="Tabletės" />
            <local:IconLabelView IconSource="drops_icon.png" Text="Lašai" />
        </x:Array>
    </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

My goal is to have such selector but with icon next to text:
[image: Selector in xamarin with text and no icon]

Comment: You could roll your own using a CollectionView or ListView inside a modal

Comment: Could you provide an example how to do that in the answer? I am very new to xamarin and have no idea what you mean

Comment: Good answer by @Andrew, which is probably your best bet here, since working with custom renderers will be difficult for this. There is no ItemTemplate, because the Picker control uses the native controls of the underlying target platform, which is why they look so different between Android, iOS and UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can roll this your self using a CollectionView inside a modal/popup page.

To get started, install the [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) nugget in your projects and follow the [setup instructions](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Getting-started).

From there, add your modal popup page. In the XAML, setup your view however your want with your CollectionView and OK and Cancel buttons. Here's what mine looks like. Disclaimer, it's pretty ugly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<popup:PopupPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:popup="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="delete.PickerModal"
    x:Name="this">
    <AbsoluteLayout
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <StackLayout
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5, .5, .7, .7"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <CollectionView
                    BackgroundColor="White"                        
                    x:Name="pickerCollection"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Source={x:Reference this}}"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Text="Cancel" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
                <Button Text="OK" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</popup:PopupPage>
```

Note that the CollectionView has a nasty habit of taking up more space than it should, so I wrapped in an AbsoluteLayout to constrain it.

In the CodeBehind, you'll add your items and handle the closing:

```
namespace delete
{   
    public partial class PickerModal : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
    {
        public PickerModal(IList<IconLabelView> items)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<IconLabelView> Items { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<IconLabelView>();

        public IconLabelView SelectedItem { get; set; }

        async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedItem = pickerCollection.SelectedItem as IconLabelView;
            await Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I'm setting the SelectedItem whenever the page is closed by either button clicked. You'll want to change that to match your expected behavior.

On my main page, I just have a button to open the picker, and a label to show the result:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="delete.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Open Picker" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
        <Label x:Name="selectedLabel" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

In the code behind, when the button is clicked, I set the items, new up the page, hook up to the disappearing event, and show the page. In the disappearing event, I grab the page, set the label text to the SelectedItem.Text, and unhook from the page.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var items = new List<IconLabelView>
        {
            new IconLabelView {Text = "Tablets", IconSource = "funny.png"},
            new IconLabelView {Text = "Liquid", IconSource = "funny.png"},
            new IconLabelView {Text = "IV", IconSource = "funny.png"},
        };
        var picker = new PickerModal(items);
        picker.Disappearing += Picker_Disappearing;
        await Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(picker);
    }

    private void Picker_Disappearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = sender as PickerModal;
        selectedLabel.Text = picker.SelectedItem.Text;
        picker.Disappearing -= Picker_Disappearing;
    }
}
```

Note that are most certainly better ways to handle some parts such as setting the items or getting the selected item, but it should get your started.

Images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the first code? Should I create ContentView for it? Its a separate file, right, but whats its type?

Comment: It's a content page with XAML. Once you've added it, you'll change it from inheriting from ContentPage to PopupPage as shown above.

Comment: But I cant do that, I get "Partial declarations of 'PickerModal' must not specify different base classes" error

Comment: You have change them in both the .cs and the XAML file. See above